# Spark 2.0.0: read many .gz files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have more than 150,000 .csv.gz files, organised in several folders (on s3) that have the same prefix. The size of each file is approximately 550KB. My goal is to read all these files into one DataFrame, the total size is about 80GB.

I am using EMR 5.0.0 with a decent cluster: 3 instances of c4.8xlarge
(36 vCPU, 60 GiB memory, EBS Storage:100 GiB).

I am reading the files using a wildcard character in the path:

```
sc.textFile("s3://bucket/directory/prefix*/*.csv.gz")
```

Then I do some map operations and I transform the RDD into a DataFrame by calling `toDF("col1_name", "col2_name", "col3_name")`. I then do few calls to UDFs to create new columns.

When I call `df.show()` the operation take longtime and never finish.

I wonder why the process is taking very long time?

Is reading that large number of .csv.gz files is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.gz` files are *not* splittable and will result in 150K partitions. Spark will *not* like that: it struggles with even several 10k's of partitions.

You might want to look into `aws distcp` or `S3DistCp` to copy to hdfs first - and then bundle the files using an appropriate `Hadoop InputFormat` such as `CombineFileInputFormat` that gloms many files into one.   Here is an older blog that has more ideas:  http://inquidia.com/news-and-info/working-small-files-hadoop-part-3